# Is the colimit of regular rings still regular?

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $I$ be a directed set. $\{R_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a direct system of regular rings. Can we deduce the direct limit of $R_i$ is still regular? (Here by "regular" we means its localization at any prime ideal is a regular local ring.) Could you prove it or give a counterexample? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true as long as the direct limit $R = \varinjlim_{i \in I} R_i$ is Noetherian; see [[Swan 1998](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1697953), Lemma 1.4]. You can also look at [[Asgharzadeh 2018](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2017.09.008)] for some related statements when $R$ is not necessarily Noetherian.